# JSON to table formatting with blanks filled in

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures, javascript-objects

Here's an example of my JSON:

```
{
    "2017-05-06": {
        "13": {
            "Chris": "2", "Ian": "3"
        },
        "14": {
            "Chris": "4", "Rob": "4"
        },
        "16": {
            "Ian": "3", "Rob": 2
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, I need it to use JS to be able to display it in a table, and with any gaps filled with zeros, the column headers (hours) in sequence, even if they're empty, and total columns and rows.

```
2017-05-06
        13   14   15   16    T
Chris    2    4    0    0    6
Ian      3    0    0    3    6
Rob      0    4    0    2    6
Total    5    8    0    5   18
```

I've no idea where to start, so would really appreciate any assistance or advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by making two arrays, one for the rows and one for the columns, that contain all the row and column titles/keys that you want to display. Then iterate the row array/col array to build a table, if there is data for row+col write it otherwise write zero. Keep total variables summing as you go.

```js
var data = {
  "2017-05-06": {
    "13": {"Chris": "2", "Ian": "3"}, 
    "14": {"Chris": "4", "Rob": "4"}, 
    "16": {"Ian": "3", "Rob": 2}
  }
};

var d = data['2017-05-06'];

var keys = Object.keys(d).sort();
// from the lowest and highest "hours" values, create an array containing everything in between too
var hours = [];
for (var i = keys[0]; i <= keys[keys.length - 1]; i++) {
  hours.push(i);
}

// get the unique names
var names = [];
for (var k in d) {
  for (var l in d[k]) {
    if (names.indexOf(l) === -1) names.push(l);
  }
}
var colTotals = {'total':0};
var tbl = "<table><thead><tr><th>Name</th>";
for (var i=0,h; h = hours[i]; i++) {
  tbl += "<th>" + h + "</th>";
  colTotals[h] = 0;
}
tbl += "<th>Total</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
for (var i=0,n; n = names[i]; i++) {
  tbl += "<tr><td>" + n + "</td>";
  var total = 0;
  for (var j=0,h; h = hours[j]; j++) {
    tbl += "<td>";
    // if data contains values for this row/col, add to total and table, otherwise put a zero
    if (d[h] && d[h][n]) {
      total += (d[h][n] - 0);
      colTotals[h] += (d[h][n] - 0);      
      
      tbl += d[h][n];
    } else {
      tbl += "0";
    }
    tbl += "</td>";
  }
  colTotals['total'] += total;
  tbl += "<td>" + total + "</td></tr>";
}
tbl += "<tr><td></td>";
for (var i=0,h; h = hours[i]; i++) {
  tbl += "<td>" + colTotals[h] + "</td>";
}
tbl += "<td>" + colTotals['total'] + "</td></tr>";
tbl += "</tbody></table>";

document.getElementById('t').innerHTML = tbl;
```

```html
<div id='t'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @James - I really liked this method when I implemented it and found it easy to expand too.

Answer (score 1):

You could collect all totals in the given object and collect the rows and columns as well as the missing ones, then iterate rows and columns and build the table with the given data.

```js
var data = { "2017-05-06": { 13: { Chris: "2", Ian: "3" }, 14: { Chris: "4", Rob: "4" }, 16: { Ian: "3", Rob: 2 } } };

Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k) {
    var table = document.createElement('table'),
        rows = [],
        cols = Object.keys(data[k])
            .sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; })
            .reduce(function (r, a) {
                var i = +r[r.length - 1];
                while (++i < a) {
                    r.push(i.toString());
                }
                r.push(a);
                return r;
            }, []);

    data[k].total = { total: 0 };

    cols.forEach(function (l) {
        var sub = data[k][l] || {};
        Object.keys(sub).forEach(function (m) {
            if (rows.indexOf(m) === -1) {
                rows.push(m);
            }
            data[k].total[m] = (data[k].total[m] || 0) + +sub[m];
            data[k].total.total += +sub[m];
            sub.total = (sub.total || 0) + +sub[m];
        });
    });

    cols.unshift('');
    cols.push('total');
    rows.unshift('');
    rows.push('total')
    rows.forEach(function (r) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        cols.forEach(function (c) {
            var t = document.createElement(r && c ? 'td' : 'th'),
                v = r && c ? (data[k][c] || {})[r] || 0 : r || c;

            t.appendChild(document.createTextNode(v));
            if (v == +v) {
                t.style.textAlign = 'right';
            }
            tr.appendChild(t);
        });
        table.appendChild(tr);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(k));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    document.body.appendChild(table);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is I take out the min hour and the max hour as the column names, and retrieve the different names as the names of the rows, then loop the rows and columns and add data from the data object to the table, if there is no data, default is 0.

```js
var jsonData = `{
  "2017-05-06": {
    "13": {
      "Chris": "2", "Ian": "3"
    },
    "14": {
      "Chris": "4", "Rob": "4"
    },
    "16": {
      "Ian": "3", "Rob": 2
    }
  }
}`;

var objData, obj, arrName, arrHour, minHour, maxHour,
    table, row, cell, caption;

objData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
obj = objData["2017-05-06"];

arrHour = Object.keys(obj);
minHour = Math.min(...arrHour);
maxHour = Math.max(...arrHour);

arrName = [];

for (let i in obj) {
  for (let j in obj[i]) {
    if (!arrName.includes(j)) {
      arrName.push(j);
    }
  }
}

table = document.createElement("table");
table.cellPadding = 2;
table.style.fontFamily = "monospace";
table.style.textAlign = "center";

caption = table.createCaption();
caption.innerText = "2017-05-06";
caption.style.textAlign = "left";
row = table.insertRow();
row.insertCell();

for (let i = minHour; i <= maxHour; i++) {
  cell = row.insertCell();
  cell.innerText = i;
}

cell = row.insertCell();
cell.innerText = "Tt";

for (let i = 0; i < arrName.length; i++) {
  let totalRow = 0;

  row = table.insertRow();
  cell = row.insertCell();
  cell.style.textAlign = "left";
  cell.innerText = arrName[i];
  
  for (let j = minHour; j <= maxHour; j++) {
    cell = row.insertCell();

    if (obj[j] !== undefined) {
      if (obj[j][arrName[i]] !== undefined) {
        cell.innerText = obj[j][arrName[i]];
        totalRow += +obj[j][arrName[i]];
      }
      else {
        cell.innerText = 0;
      }
    }
    else {
      cell.innerText = 0;
    }
  }
  
  cell = row.insertCell();
  cell.innerText = totalRow;
}

row = table.insertRow();
row.innerText = "Total";

for (let i = 0; i <= maxHour - minHour + 1; i++) {
  let totalCol = 0;
  cell = row.insertCell();

  for (let j = 0; j < arrName.length; j++) {
    totalCol += +table.rows[j + 1].cells[i + 1].innerText;
  }

  cell.innerText = totalCol;
}

document.body.appendChild(table);
```